# How to print collection view

Tags: swift

I am thinking of using UICollectionview to show some data.

How can I export it to pdf or other printable formats.

Before getting started with it I want to know if it would even be possible to do or maybe use something else to get the same results

Comment: You can create pdf with collectionview

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can render to UIKit, including a collectionView you can render to PDF using [UIGraphicsPDFRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicspdfrenderer) (see linked apple docs for example).  The real issue is whether or not you *should* do this and the answer is probably no.  If you render a view or its layer to the pdf it gets rasterized at the screen resolution which may be high density for a phone, but isn't necessarily high density for a pdf (especially on something like an iPhone SE).  Whether or not you care is up to you, but if you are using vectors to draw your collection view (that includes text) then you are much better off drawing those vectors directly in the pdf context than just rendering the view.  Same for Raster images.  If you have a a higher resolution image draw it directly into the pdf context instead of rendering the imageview.  It's more work, but you will get better results.  If you don't care, you certainly can just render the view straight to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can rather use a UIScrollView 
Here is a tutorial on how to do just that:

https://medium.com/@bermaniastudios/generating-a-pdf-from-a-uiscrollview-7dff2045bc31

This works with UIScrollView subclasses UITableView and UICollectionView as well.